# Compile Quarkus application to a DLL (library)

Tags: dll, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Could a Quarkus application be compiled to a DLL?

I have some code written in Java with Quarkus and it can compile to an .exe on windows, and it would be useful to be able to call that code from my native application in Visual C++, so if the Quarkus application could be compiled to a DLL then I could do that.

Quarkus comes with many useful libraries which can be used from Java code which compile to native.

Answer (score 4):

Quarkus uses [GraalVM native image technology](https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/) to compile applications to native binares.

You can use native image to compile to shared libraries. For example, GraalVM distributions include the GraalVM JIT compiler, which is a Java application originally, but when you run `java` by default it uses the shared library built from the Java code of the JIT compiler. This shared library is built with native image of course.

You can see a small example of how to do it in this [blogpost about GraalVM](https://medium.com/p/12d9111f307d#f8cc). Or in this doc showing how to compile Java code to a shared library (and consume it through JNI): https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/ImplementingNativeMethodsInJavaWithSVM/#create-a-shared-library
Naturally, you don't have to consume your library through JNI, but can do it from any other language or environment.

This excellent article from Michael Simons goes through the example how to build Neo4j Java driver to a shared library and consume that from C code: https://medium.com/graalvm/3-ways-to-polyglot-with-graalvm-fb28c1542b45 ("Bringing Java over to C" section).

In a nutshell, you mark methods that you want to expose with the `@CEntryPoint` annotation, and add the `--shared` flag to the native image options.
The result is a shared library and a header file for the library.

There's a little bit of ceremony required before using shared libraries built by native image, namely you need to create an `Isolate` before calling into the shared library, you do that by calling a provided function:

```
int graal_create_isolate(graal_create_isolate_params_t* params, graal_isolate_t** isolate, graal_isolatethread_t** thread);
```

Another thing you might want to do is to expose the `main` method as an entry point and call that before you start calling into the other exposed methods. This will (I think) initialize the application, do the dependency injection wiring, and so on. This is usually not necessary for the libraries, but since the application lifecycle is managed by the framework you probably need to do it.